Show that $C$ is separately independent of $A,B$ implies that $C$ is jointly independent of $A,B$ here
Let

$(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
$Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$;
$\alpha:E^2\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$-measurable;
$(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
$(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued processes on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N;$$
$(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a real-valued independent identically $\mathcal U_{[0,\;1)}$-distributed process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

Assume

$(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ and $(U_k)_{k\ge n}$ are independent;
$$X_n=\begin{cases}Y_n&\text{, if }U_n<\alpha(Z_n);\\X_{n-1}&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\tag2$$
$$\operatorname P\left[Y_n\in B\mid X_{n-1}\right]=Q(X_{n-1},B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E\tag3$$

for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain.

I've tried this for a long time now, but I fail to show that

$(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n,U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$ and $U_n$ are independent for all $n\in\mathbb N$;
$((U_n,Z_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain.


Regarding 4.: By assumption, $A:=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ and $C:=U_n$ are independent and $B:=(U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$ and $C=U_n$ are independent. However, in general it does not follow that $(A,B)$ and $C$ are independent. So we need another argument to conclude.
Regarding 5.: $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a (trivial) time-homogeneous Markov chain and $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain. However, once again we need another argument to conclude. (The conclusion would be easy, if $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would be independent, but they are clearly not.)
